# How to fix python Syntax error unicodeescape error?

Tags: python, pycharm

so I have a error after running this code, I have no idea what is wrong with it. Could someone help me with that please? [image]

Comment: Next time please post your code and error message as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` in your path. You can do that with `\\` or with a raw string.

```py
# Escape
path = "C:\\users\\something\\a"

# Or with a raw string
path = r"C:\users\something"
```

Comment: Or you could just use forward slashes (yes, even on Windows): `path = "C:/users/something"`

Comment: By the way, how can I numerate from 1 not from 0?

Comment: Look at the documentation of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). There is an optional second parameter.